# How to sort a Pandas pivot table but keep totals at end of table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I built a pivot table doing this:

`prima_neta = df.pivot_table(index = ["seccion"], columns = "operacion", values = "prima_pesos", aggfunc = "sum", margins=True).fillna(0)`

and then tried to sort the table in descending order by 'All' column (generated by `margins=True`):

`prima_neta.sort_values(by='All', ascending=False)`

This works fine, but the 'All' total (which of course is the highest amount) at the end of the original table output is brought up to the top as first line.

I would like to sort the table in descending order, but keep the 'All' (Totals) amounts at the last line.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are going to have to create a pseudo-sortkey.  Add, some data to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

# Create dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice([*'ABC'], 36)
                  ,'B':np.random.choice([*'xyz'], 36)
                  ,'C':np.random.randint(0,100,36)})

# Pivot table with margins
results = df.pivot_table('C', 'A', 'B', aggfunc='sum', margins=True)

#Create temporary sortkey sort on sortkey and values, drop sortkey
result = results.assign(sortkey=results.index == 'All')\
                .sort_values(['sortkey','All'], ascending=[True, False])\
                .drop('sortkey', axis=1)
result
```

Output:

```
B      x    y    z   All
A                       
B    368  215  275   858
A    155  202  218   575
C    206  149   45   400
All  729  566  538  1833
```

Comment: WOW !  Amazing. Worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can just swap the two rows.

```
ndf = df.reset_index()
totalind = ndf.index[ndf.All=='total'].tolist()[0]
ind = np.array(ndf.index)
ind[totaling], ind[-1] = ind.iloc[-1], ind.iloc[totalind]
ndf.reindex(ind)
```

There should be a less painful way, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set_index column

Comment: Are you trying to post an answer or are commenting on another answer? With so little written, it's hard to tell what the purpose of your post is and how this addresses the question. If this is an answer, please [edit] your post to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).